# How do I generate 135,960 players using the following code and generate_series()

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Write a script that populates the database with 624,680 matches and 135,960 players.

We are specifying an exact number of tuples in each table for consistency and usage in different parts in the assignment. You must insert players with name that contain the word “salah” 22,218 times.

So far, here are the details in my POSTgreSQL in `played_in` column:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.played_in
(
    mid integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    year date,
    "position" integer,
    CONSTRAINT played_in_pkey PRIMARY KEY (name),
    CONSTRAINT pk UNIQUE (mid),
    CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (mid)
        REFERENCES public.cup_matches (mid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.played_in
    OWNER to postgres;
```

How do I generate 135,960 players with their information?

I know I must put a `generate_series` line in the code, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Note that `mid` is unique and also a foreign key on cup_matches so you need 135960 unique cup_matches.mid values first,   only then can you get data into `played_in`  Are you sure mid should be a unique constraint? By itself, generate series isn't complex e.g. `SELECT blah, blah FROM generate_series(1, 135960)`

Answer (score 1):

- [`gen_random_uuid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) to spawn some text values.
- [`random()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE) to get random numerical data.
- Basic arithmetics and [casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) to get them in certain types and ranges.
- [`with` common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to populate both tables at once
- [Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) of `text`, from which a random index is selected to get one-of-N values.
- [`overlay()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.5.2.2.10.1.1.1) with `random()` as the *`start`* index to inject `'salah'` into random section of selected names
- For `'salah'` to occur in the name of around 16% players (22218 out of 135960), you can use `random()>0.2` to aim for 20%, then a [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) count those and to stop at exactly 22218.

[Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/LySVsckb)

```sql
create sequence salah_insertions as int minvalue 1;

with populate_cup_matches as (
  insert into cup_matches 
  select generate_series(1,624680,1) as mid,
         ('{final,semi-final,quarter-final,16,32}'::text[])[ceil(random()*5)] as round,
         'epoch'::date+'1 year'::interval*floor(random()*53) as year,
         floor(random()*100)::int as num_ratings,
         random()*100 as rating
  returning *
)
insert into public.played_in
select mid,
       case when random()<=0.2 and nextval('salah_insertions')<=22218
            then overlay(gen_random_uuid()::varchar(30) 
                         placing 'salah' 
                         from ceil(random()*26)::int )
            else gen_random_uuid()::varchar(30) 
       end as name,
       year,
       random()*100 as position
from populate_cup_matches limit 135960
returning *;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply, but do you know why this error comes out to me?

ERROR:  Key (mid)=(1) is not present in table "cup_matches".insert or update on table "played_in" violates foreign key constraint "fk" 

ERROR:  insert or update on table "played_in" violates foreign key constraint "fk"
SQL state: 23503
Detail: Key (mid)=(1) is not present in table "cup_matches".

Comment: @AbdelrahmanBusairi You haven't shown the structure of `cup_matches` but in general you should be able to build a similar insert statement in a `with` Common Table Expression, then run your `played_in` insert outside it. That way you can populate both of the tables at once, making sure that when `played_in` gets a row, its corresponding row in `cup_matches` is already present. I've updated the answer and the demo.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.cup_matches
(
    mid integer NOT NULL,
    round character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    year date,
    num_ratings integer,
    rating double precision,
    CONSTRAINT cup_matches_pkey PRIMARY KEY (mid)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.cup_matches
    OWNER to postgres;



Im sorry the code seems crammed here

Comment: As you can see in the update, that's done pretty much the same way, for however many tables you need, linked or not. I've also added the `salah` into the name in 22218 cases.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!
Do you know if I can make the round only contain 5 values, which are (32, 16, quarter-final, semi-final, and final only?)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanBusairi Sure, that you can do very close to how you've put it in plain words: set up an `array` of options, then let `random()` pick a random one of the five. You said *"(32, 16, quarter-final, semi-final, and final only?)"* and you can turn it into `('{32, 16, quarter-final, semi-final, final}'::text[])` to make it an array of options, then add a `[ceil(random()*5)::int]` to let `random()` hit one of the five options, randomly. See the update.

Comment: Also, note that you'll need to widen `round character varying(10)` to `varchar(13)` for `'quarter-final'` to fit (it's 13 characters long): `ALTER TABLE public.cup_matches ALTER COLUMN round TYPE varchar(13);`. Keep in mind the random function will not attempt to give you perfectly uniform distribution, so you won't likely get 20% of each option, more like 19%,18%,21%,20%,22%.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you've been a great help. Though do you know how do I make the year as only the year without including 01-01, for days and months? Just year

Comment: You can use `extract(year from your_timestamp_value)` or `to_char(timestamp_value, 'YYYY')` but it's best to only use that for presentation, while the table still saves actual `timestamp`-type value, that lets you use adequate, built-in functions and operators with it.

Comment: I received an issue where the round usually results in null, do you know a way where I should make all my values not null? I added the constraint and it said I cannot run it due to some random values resulted in null in round

Comment: That's probably because of missing `ceil()` function I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344865/how-do-i-generate-135-960-players-using-the-following-code-and-generate-series/76345681?noredirect=1#comment134631578_76345681) but then used the code without it when I updated the answer earlier.

Comment: Oh, I didnt see the ciel() one, my apologies. Thank you for the help, but one more thing: Do you know a way where I can insert players with name that contain the 
word “salah” 22,218 times across the entire from populate_cup_matches limit 135960, while they can appear randomly without any specific formula

Comment: `overlay()` to inject 'salah' into random part of the name, `random()>0.2` with a sequence to attempt random distribution of those 22218 cases. See the updated answer and [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LySVsckb). At this point it might be better if you collect all these additional requests/criteria and edit the question, adding them as a tidy list.