# How to write a PostgreSQL query to sort and group records with 'Luxary' and 'Mid' categories, making 'Mid' records show on the top?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a requirement in production, for which i am not sure how to write the query in postgresql.

As I cannot put the production details, created a sample table and data.

```
CREATE TABLE public.tbl_practice 
(
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    category varchar NULL,
    created timestamp NULL
);
```

Sample data:

```
id   category   created
---------------------------------------
 1   Luxary     2022-09-20 15:35:01.000
 2   Mid        2022-10-20 15:35:01.000
 3   Luxary     2022-09-21 15:35:01.000
 4   Mid        2022-12-20 15:35:01.000
```

Now, I want to fetch the data in such a way that all 'Luxary' records and 'Mid' record be together and sorted in created by desc, also 'Mid' category records should always show at the top.

What I tried? I used window function of postgresql and wrote this query, but I am not getting the desired result

```
select 
    category, max(created) over (partition by category) 
from 
    tbl_practice
```

'Mid' is at the end also my created date is overridden

```
category  max
---------------------------------
Luxary    2022-09-21 15:35:01.000
Luxary    2022-09-21 15:35:01.000
Mid       2022-12-20 15:35:01.000
Mid       2022-12-20 15:35:01.000
```

Expected result

```
Mid     2022-12-20 15:35:01.000
Mid     2022-10-20 15:35:01.000
Luxary  2022-09-21 15:35:01.000
Luxary  2022-09-20 15:35:01.000
```

Answer (score 1):

To manually specify the order, you could use a [`case`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) statement in your `order by`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/sBqtPfRs)

```sql
select category,created
from tbl_practice
order by case category 
           when 'Mid'    then 0 --in asc order, 0 will come first
           when 'Luxury' then 1 --in asc order, 1 will come second
           else 2               --all else comes after the above
         end asc nulls last, 
         created asc nulls last;
```

You could also look into [enumerated types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html) to make `Mid` and `Luxury` lower/higher value enums that would be sorted accordingly without having to use the `case`:

```sql
create type category_enum as enum (
    'Mid',   --this will be interpreted as low numerical value
    'Luxury' --this will be interpreted as a higher numerical value
);

alter table tbl_practice         --redefining the table
   alter column category         --modifying the column
   type category_enum            --changing the column type
   using category::category_enum --specifies how to migrate from the old type
;

select category,created
from tbl_practice
order by category, --categories now act like numbers: 'Mid' comes 1st, Luxury 2nd
         created;
```

Comment: thanks for correcting the Luxury Part :)
i replicated your solution fine in my product also, thanks alot for the help.
Just needed more info on how to understand the query also how can i get better on this?
@Zegarek

Comment: @SuddatShende I've added some comments to the answer in hope it'll be a bit clearer. Do you mean getting better at writing PostgreSQL queries, or is there something specific about this one that you'd like to improve?

Comment: thanks for adding the comments.
yes i want to get better at writing sql queries, like i was thinking sub-queries and window functions, where as your query is easy to read and quite simple to be honest, i would also like to improve on the same. If you could help or share some resources how i can get better at it.@Zegarek

Comment: PostgreSQL documentation has a fairly good [tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial.html) in it: [there's even a separate section on window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). That one is a pretty reliable starting point while being completely free. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is handy as a testbench, freeing you from having to set up and maintain your own db, plus you can easily show and discuss it with people.

Comment: Generating [a lot of thorough test data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76345681/5298879) is helpful to see how things perform, scale and break, and so is [analyzing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) how they behave and what they do exactly in the process.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information @Zegarek
i will go through the tutorial and other resources you have mentioned!